# Detect if the Button is Enabled or Disabled in Livecode

Tags: button, detect, livecode

How can I detect if the button is enabled/disabled in livecode?

I want to display an alert box that determines if the button is disabled/enabled.

I tried these scripts but it doesn't work...

```
if button "button" is disabled then
   answer "button is disabled"
else
   answer "button is enabled"
end if
```

Comment: Whoever voted this down should have added a comment to explain why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I notice that you start all your script lines with capitals. I'd recommend starting your lines with lower case characters. That will give you more flexibility with regard to camel-caps syntax that is so typical of LiveCode scripts.

You can't compare a control to a constant. A constant is basically a string and you can only compare strings with strings. Because a button is a control instead of a string, you can't compare a button and a constant.

Second, disabled is a property and not a constant. In your script, you treat is like a constant. A property is always "of a control" unless it is a global property. That means that you need to have "of" in your syntax. You can write `the disabled of button "name of your button"`. Please, don't use "button" as a name for your button, because eventually that may confuse both you and the LiveCode engine.

The following script should work.

```
if the disabled of button "My Button" is true then
  answer "The button is disabled"
else
  answer "The button is enabled"
end if
```

Because `the disabled of button "My Button"` returns either `true` or `false` and `the disabled of button "My Button" is true` also evaluates to either `true`or `false`, you can also just write

```
if the disabled of button "My Button" then
  answer "The button is disabled"
else
  answer "The button is enabled"
end if
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. I'm using phone to post this question so my codes start with capital letters.